# MySql nested view return blank or 0 instead null value

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join

I have weird result for select when there is view in left join table

User view:

```html
CREATE VIEW user_view AS 
    SELECT
        t1.app_user_pk,
        t1.app_user_id,
        t1.app_user_username,
        t1.app_user_email,
        t1.app_user_active,
        t1.app_user_changed,
        t1.app_user_created,
        t2.role_pk,
        t2.role_id
    FROM
        app_user t1
        INNER JOIN role t2 ON t1.role_fk = t2.role_id
```

Select:

```html
SELECT
    t1.tile_pk,
    t1.tile_id,
    t1.tile_name,
    t3.app_user_pk,
    t3.app_user_id,
    t3.role_pk,
    t3.role_id
  FROM tile t1
      LEFT JOIN user_view t3
      ON t1.app_user_fk = t3.app_user_id
```

The result:

[Select result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnVrU.png)

You can see that after the left join is null that next row has 0 for role_pk instead correct number and blank for role_id instead id.

If I remove user_view and make role join in select it will work.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect the result of a `inner join` and `left join` to be same?

Comment: @XING no I don't expect but for example the row with tile_pk 27 should have role_id with value instead blank like now. It is ok when value is NULL but I getting 0 or blank when the value should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have that problem only on my laptop. I made SQL Fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a21b28/2) and result is what I expect (normal). But when I run that sql fiddle on my laptop I get the wrong result.
I use HeidiSql with version 5.7.11.